# How to initialize big immutable map in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, initialization, containers

I have a big dataset. It contains more than 1000 records. This dataset maps one string to another. So it is convenient to use `Map<String, String>`. The data inside this map are not changed during the application run so the immutable map is ok.

The only way of initialization of Map I found is mapOf function:

```
testMap = mapOf("One" to "1", "Two" to "2", "Eight" to "8")
```

But I cannot place the whole of my dataset in one line. It is very inconvenient and the code looks totally unreadable and ugly.
The more convenient way of initialization is to read the dataset from a txt file line by line in loop and fill the map by these lines.

Is it possible to fill Map in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap`, and initialize like this:

```
val map = hashMapOf<String,String>()
for (i in 0..1000){
    // Logic to read txt
    map["key"] = "value"
}
```